# Error while assigning current directory to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash  
    if [ "$outDir" == "" ]
    then
        echo "$PWD" ,"We are here ", $outDir ," with " 
        "$outDir" = "$PWD"
        echo "Yes"
    fi
```

Output on terminal:

`/home/Documents/folderName ,We are here , , with`

`./pipeline.sh: line 28: : command not found`

`Yes`

I am unable to assign the current directory to $outDir.

I tried `"outDir" = "$PWD"` and `$outDir="$PWD"` and `"$outDir"=$PWD` , but nothing worked. However, `echo $PWD` works perfectly fine.

Why it doesn't *work*?

Comment: To test if variable is a directory try `if [ -d "$outDir" ]` or for negative test `if [ ! -d "$outDir" ]`.

Comment: jimmij - Thank you for your reply. I have made $outDir optional in my script. If user provides then I will check, otherwise, I want to make it current directory, i.e *PWD*

Comment: Then definitely `${outDir:=$PWD}`. The most widespread use of that form is for environment defaults. The variable will test itself. oh. but it definitely doesn't test for an actual directory.

Comment: mikserv - Yes, I know it won't check. I shall add all the test(s). :) 

The assignment is where I struggled. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you're trying to assign `$PWD` to `$outDir` only in the event that `$outDir` is unset or of null value, yes?

The following is equivalent, I think:

```
printf 'We are here: "%s"\n $outDir = "%s"\n' \ 
    "$PWD" "${outDir:=$PWD}"
```

If `$outDir` is already assigned a value then, for `printf`'s second argument, that prints its value, else it simultaneously assigns the value of `$PWD` to `$outDir` and prints it.

Of course, though here the `${outDir:=$PWD}` variable call self-corrects a null or unset value, it makes no attempt to verify it is *actually a directory*. The same is true of your check above. And so probably better than either of these is:

```
cd -- "${outDir:=$PWD}" || exit; cd - >/dev/null
```

`cd` will not only verify that the user's selection for `$outDir` is correct, it will also print an error if it is not or is not accessible to the user. `cd -` will just bring you back to where you were before testing with `cd` in the first place in the event of a successful test. The `>/dev/null` redirection is just to keep `cd -` from printing `$PWD` which it will do when used otherwise.

If the user has not assigned `$outDir`, however, then its value is just assigned to the value of `$PWD` as before, which implies a successful test and two `cd $PWD` commands in succession as the `-` is substituted for `$OLDPWD` - which is here also `$PWD`.

Comment: mikeserv . That works. But, when I assign, I get a message saying `/home/Documents/folderName: Is a directory`

Thank you.

Comment: @DeathMetal - this is probably because the `\`backslash above isn't correctly escaping a `\n`ewline and so the arguments I intended for `printf` are instead falling into their own line. Make sure there are no spaces or any other characters following the backslash, or else just put it all on a single line with no backslash at all.

Comment: `${outDir:=$PWD}`

What I did is only took the assignment part of your code. I don't want to print.  

Thanks for `cd  -- ` code, it is *awesome* ;)

Comment: @DeathMetal - yes, that explains it. Understand that the form `"${var:=val}"` doesn't equate to `var="val"` because it doesn't evaluate to the assignment, but rather to the *value* of the assignment. Instead it equates to `var="val"; "$var"` and so it should be used inline and not as a command in itself. `: "${var:=val}"` works just fine in that context. And also remember that it only ever assigns if `$var` is empty or unset. Omitting the `:` like `"${var=val}"` would preserve even an empty pre-existing value for `$var` and assign it only if it is definitely already unset.

Answer (score 0):

```
outDir="$PWD"
```

Furthermore: It seems more useful to me to use `echo` with just one argument:

```
echo "${PWD} ,We are here , ${outDir} , with "
```

The `if` test could be replaced by

```
if [ -z "$outDir" ]
```

Comment: @ "Hauke Laging"

I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newline after the first echo command so `"$outDir" = "$PWD"` is being treated as a command.

You can either append `"$outDir" = "$PWD"` to the first echo line or add a line continuation character at the end of the first echo line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
if [ "$outDir" == "" ]
then
    echo "$PWD" ,"We are here ", $outDir ," with ", \
    "$outDir" = "$PWD"
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

Or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
if [ "$outDir" == "" ]
then
    echo "$PWD" ,"We are here ", $outDir ," with ", "$outDir" = "$PWD"
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

Will give you the output you desire:

```
[sri@localhost ~]$ ./crap.bsh 
./crap.bsh 
/home/sri ,We are here , , with ,  = /home/sri
Yes
```

**Here is the text of my first answer.**  Disregard.

It does work (on my box) and I'm shocked that it did.  First here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$outDir" == "" ]
then
    echo "$PWD", "We are here", $outDir, "$outDir" = "$PWD"
    echo "yes"
fi
```

Here is the output

```
./test.bsh
/home/chris, We are here, ,  = /home/chris
yes
```

I assume it has something to do with your bash version.  Here is mine:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

I've been writing BASH scripts for 20 years and I didn't expect this to work.  That script must have been written using a syntax that is supported in newer versions of BASH.

I personally would have one string to do this.  I've never seen anybody do what you did before (I think that's cool):

```
echo "$PWD, We are here, $outDir, $outDir = $PWD"
```

Also remember that you can avoid variable expansion by using single quotes:

```
echo "$PWD"
echo '$PWD'
echo "$(pwd)"
```

output:

```
/home/chris
$PWD
/home/chris
```

Comment: `echo` has always `echo`ed its arguments. A comma is an argument, too.

Comment: Yes, you right.  I meant to convey  that in 20 years of writing BASH scripts I've never seen it done like that.  In other words, you learn something new everyday.

Comment: I am using `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I see what's wrong.  There is a newline after "with ".      '"$outDir" = "$PWD"' is being interpreted as a command.  Append  '"$outDir" = "$PWD"' after "with " and it will work.

Comment: Or you can just put '\' after "with ".  I think someone already said that.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear.